# Using hypergraphs in pygraph, need verification that example is correct

Tags: python, graph-theory, graphviz, pygraph

I am trying to get my head around using hypergraphs in pygraph, the following is a simple example I inserted:

```
hgr = hypergraph()
hgr.add_nodes(["A1", "B1", "C1", "D1"]) 
hgr.add_nodes(["A2", "B2", "C2", "D2"])
hgr.add_nodes(["A3", "B3", "C3", "D3"])
hgr.add_nodes(["A4", "B4", "C4", "D4"])

hgr.add_hyperedge(("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"))
hgr.add_hyperedge(("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4"))
hgr.add_hyperedge(("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"))
hgr.add_hyperedge(("D1", "D2", "D3", "D4"))

h_dot = write(hgr)
h_gvv = gv.readstring(h_dot)
gv.layout(h_gvv,'dot')
gv.render(h_gvv, 'png', 'hypergraph.png')
```

The image I am getting is (click to see full size version): 
[image: output of above hypergraph construction]

Please verify that this is the correct way to create hypergraphs using pygraph.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Apologies didn't know how to enlarge image!

Answer (score 3):

Since each hyperedge isn't a collection of nodes, but instead represented as a node, you should use an unique (simple) identifier for the [hyperedges](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1823095/python-graph/docs/pygraph.classes.hypergraph.hypergraph-class.html#add_hyperedge), just as you do for the nodes, and then [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1823095/python-graph/docs/pygraph.classes.hypergraph.hypergraph-class.html#link) them to the nodes.

Consider the example graph in the [Wikipedia article for hypergraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph):

[image: Wikipedia hypergraph]

To create this graph in `pygraph` you could do the following:

```
from pygraph.classes.hypergraph import hypergraph
from pygraph.readwrite.dot import write_hypergraph

h = hypergraph()

h.add_nodes(['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5', 'v6', 'v7'])
h.add_hyperedges(['e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4'])

h.link('v1', 'e1')
h.link('v2', 'e1')
h.link('v3', 'e1')
h.link('v2', 'e2')
h.link('v3', 'e2')
h.link('v3', 'e3')
h.link('v5', 'e3')
h.link('v6', 'e3')
h.link('v4', 'e4')

with open('hypergraph.dot', 'w') as f:
    f.write(write_hypergraph(h))
```

which will produce this image output with `dot`:

[image: Dot hypergraph]

This is a correct representation I guess, but not as visual as the image from Wikipedia. If you are pursuing a visualization of hypergraphs, you should check out [this question](https://web.archive.org/web/20170202132818/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694602/hypergraph-visualization).